# Can I connect 2 pi's together via Ethernet cable?

Tags: wifi, ethernet

I have two rpi's both of which have a wifi dongle. I can vnc into rpi but if I connect the two rpi's via Ethernet cable, vnc fails. Is there a way to hook the two rpi together via ethernet ports and retain access via wifi?

Comment: Note that although I think I have an answer to your problem of wifi dropping out when you plug in an ethernet cable, how to connect two computers directly with an ethernet cable is a different question (and off topic here).

Comment: I read somewhere that if you have wlan0 up then eth0 goes down. You need to search about what is going on there. I think there are some configs that need chaning

Answer (score 4):

Yes, put a static ip address for eth0  in /etc/network/interfaces on both RPis. The network has to be different than that of the WiFi devices.

Comment: This may be a simpler way of getting around ifplugd instigated events since it should prevent dropping DHCP on wifi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is because of hijinks caused by [ifplugd](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifplugd/), which runs as an init service by default on raspbian.  The intent is to configure ethernet automatically when a cable is plugged in, since this is an event that the normal NetworkManager system can't detect.

To test this premise, before you plug the cable into either pi, try and stop the service on both of them:

```
service ifplugd stop
```

Make sure it is really stopped with `ps -C ifplugd` (it shouldn't list anything).  When I noticed this app on my first pi, it seemed very pesky and I had to completely uninstall it to prevent it from coming back.

Plug in the ethernet cable and see if the wifi goes down.  If so, check `ps -C ifplugd` again (you'll need a keyboard and screen plugged in to debug this, obviously).  If not, problem solved.

If the wifi goes down and `ifplugd` isn't running, you probably have to reconfigure or disable NetworkManager.